# Multiply coefficients into a matrix after meshgrid-ed in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix of `A=[60x60]`,and two coefficients `a,b`. Since matrix `A` was moved by `a,b`, how to multiply the coefficients into matrix `A` so that I could obtain `A_moved`? Any function to do it?

Here's part of matlab code implemented:

```
A=rand(60); %where it's in 2D, A(k1,k2)
a=0.5; b=0.8;
[m, n]=size(A);
[M,N] = meshgrid(1:m,1:n);
X = [M(:), N(:)];
A_moved=A(:)(X)*[a b] %I know this is not valid but you get the idea
```

In another word `A_moved` is calculated by `A_moved=a*k1+b*k2`.

This line of code `A_moved=A(:)(X)*[a b]` is to represent my idea that `a,b` multiply back into the original `A` because `X` represent correspond coordinates of `k1` and `k2`. The first column represent `k1`, and second column represent `k2`. Thus it become `A_moved=a*k1+b*k2`. But this couldn't get me anyway.

In the end `A-moved` is a `60x60` matrix which have been multiplied by coefficients `a,b` correspondingly. To make it clearer,`A` is the phase of image. `a,b` moved it phase.

Appreciate any help. Thank you!

Reference paper: [Here](https://mega.nz/#!vp9WFDbb!pEG8pem9n2SaX8IHxbUxnD4JT6ngp0nF608T3zAeiJY)

EDIT:

As suggested by Noel for better understanding.

`A=[2 3;5 7]`, `a=1.5` and `b=2.5`.

Since `A` is approximated as `a*k1+b*k2`
Thus, 
`A_moved=[1.5*k1_1+2.5k2_1 1.5*k1_2+2.5k2_2; 1.5*k1_2+2.5k2_1 1.5*k1_2+2.5k2_2];`

where `k1` and `k2`, If I'm understood correctly is the coordinates of the original `A` matrix, as defined in `X` above.

Comment: Is not clear to me what do you mean by "move by coefficients". Could you please show a small example of maybe `A=[4x4]` to show what do you want to achive?

Comment: Hi, I just edited the question to make it clearer. I can't give you the final or comparable value of `A_moved` because I have stuck at the last line of the code. But the added description should explain it more clearer.

Comment: What I meant was, can you do by hand, not by code, a small simple example to show which operations you want to perform. Because it's still not clear to me what's your objective

Comment: I have attached the reference paper in this code implementation. I really reached the end of the road here that's why I attached the paper. I'm so so sorry! Maybe the operation described in the paper is more clearer than I'm explaining here. You could just look at equation (14). It should explain.

Comment: Your link is wrong, it comes back to this page

Comment: My mistake! It's fixed.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't undestand what you want to do, maybe you can simplify it for me a little. If `A=[2 3;5 7]`, `a=1.5` and `b=2.5`, What values would you expect at `A_moved`?

Comment: Thanks Noel for being patience with me. I updated according to the values you provided. Did that explain it clearer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137812/discussion-between-noel-segura-meraz-and-j-dane).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the chat we found that your problem was matrix algebra related

What you want to obtain in `A_moved` is the x coordinate multiplied by a contant `a` plus the y coordinate multiplied by a constant `b`.

You already have this coordinates in `M` and `N`, so you can obtain `A_moved` as

```
A_moved = (a*M) + (b*N);
```

And it will retain same shape as `A`